# How to grep all characters in file

Tags: bash, grep

I have a CSV file with this lines:

```
----------+79975532211,----------+79975532212
4995876655,4995876658
```

I try to grep this lines in Bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

    config='/test/config.conf'

 sourcecsv=/test/sourse.csv

cat $sourcecsv | while read line

do

Oldnumber=$(echo $line | cut -d',' -f1)

cat $config | grep "\\$Oldnumber" -B 8


done
```

But when script grep value **4995876655** I get error:

```
grep: Invalid back reference
```

How I can grep all values in my file?

Comment: you are overquoting `... grep "$Oldnumber"...`

Comment: And a [useless use of `cat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat).

Comment: @Biffen Two of them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really mean to `grep` for all strings between commas, you can do it all in one go.

```
tr ',' '\n' </test/sourse.csv |
grep -F -f - -B 8 /test/config.conf
```

If you need to obtain the matches in sequence (all matches for the first string followed by all matches for the second, etc) then maybe loop over them with a proper `while` loop:

```
tr ',' '\n' </test/sourse.csv |
while read -r Oldnumber; do
    grep -F -B 8 -e "$Oldnumber" /test/config.conf
done
```

Keeping the file names in variables does not seem to offer any advantage here.

If you mean to search for the strings preceded by a literal backslash, you can add it back; the `-F` option I added turns all strings into literals.  If you need metacharacters, and take out the `-F` option, you need to double the backslashes (inside double quotes, a single backslash needs to be represented as double; and to get a literal backslash in a regular expression, you need two of them).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
cat $config | grep "\\$Oldnumber" -B 8
```

You should do:

```
grep -B 8 -F -- "$Oldnumber" "$config"
```

Comment: If I use `grep -B 8 -F "$Oldnumber" "$config"`
I can't grep this value  ----------+79975532211

I have this error:

`grep: unrecognized option '----------+79975532211'`